# Разделительные полоски в меню

Tags: html, css, border

Делаю с помощью border-right по  всем  div:

```
menu > * {
 border-right: 1px #b4b0b0 solid;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать самый крайний правый border?

Comment: Используйте псевдоэлемент `:not(:last-child)`.

Comment: @Arthur так не работает. В чем ошибка ? 

 `menu1 > * :not(:last-child) {  border-right: 1px #b4b0b0 solid;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }`


так работает, но длинный код:
 ` menu1 > *  {
 border-right: 1px #b4b0b0 solid;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }

menu1 :last-child {  border-right: 0px}`

Comment: Разобрался: пробел не нужен оказывается до :not  `menu1 > *:not(:last-child)`